# Busca em duas tabelas

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, select

Tenho uma tabela de mídias com os campos `id_midia`, `nome`, `tipo` e outra tabela de sinônimos que tem os campos `id_midia`, `sinônimo`.

Preciso fazer uma consulta onde ele cheque nas duas tabelas se o termo digitado está contido no nomes da mídia ou no sinônimo.

Estou fazendo dessa forma:

```
$sql = "
  SELECT ayzac_midia_name,ayzac_midia_id 
  FROM `ayzac_midia` 
  WHERE `ayzac_midia`.`ayzac_midia_name` 
  LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' 
  UNION SELECT ayzac_tag,ayzac_midia_id 
    FROM `ayzac_tags` 
    WHERE `ayzac_tags`.`ayzac_tag` 
    LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%'
";
```

Só que eu preciso das informações da tabela de mídia, e quando o termo encontrado é um sinônimo ele traz o `sinônimo` ao invés do `nome`. E também preciso do tipo na tabela de mídia e dessa forma ele só me retorna o `nome` e o `id`. Também, se o termo buscado existir nas duas tabelas com o mesmo `id` ele exibe as duas tabelas e isso não pode acontecer.

Se alguém puder me ajudar com isso eu ficaria bem grato.

@edit
Explicando o contexto:

O que estou fazendo é uma busca de filmes e séries cadastradas no meu banco de dados, acontece que o usuário não precisa necessariamente buscar pelo nome completo da mídia ele pode buscar por um sinônimo ou uma tag, por exemplo Game of Thrones pode ser buscado por GoT, mas mesmo que ele busque utilizando o termo GoT, quero que seja retornado Game of Thrones.

PS: GoT está em uma tabela apenas para os sinônimos que contem apenas o id_midia, que é um FK da tabela de mídia e o sinônimo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que você precise fazer um `JOIN` com a tabela `ayzac_midia` no segundo `SELECT` e desta forma poderá retornar o nome da `midia`.

Algo parecido com isto:

```
$sql = "SELECT ayzac_midia_name,ayzac_midia_id 
  FROM `ayzac_midia` 
  WHERE `ayzac_midia`.`ayzac_midia_name` LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%'    
  UNION 
    SELECT ayzac_tag,ayzac_midia_id, ayzac_midia.ayzac_midia_name 
    FROM `ayzac_tags`
    INNER JOIN `ayzac_midia` ON `ayzac_midia`.`ayzac_midia_id` = `ayzac_tags`.`ayzac_midia_id`
    WHERE `ayzac_tags`.`ayzac_tag` LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%'";
```

Comment: Assim que der vou tentar fazer isso, parece que vai resolver meu problema. Depois dou meu feedback

Comment: Não funcionou, deixa eu tentar explicar melhor:

O que estou fazendo é uma busca de filmes e séries cadastradas no meu banco de dados, acontece que o usuário não precisa necessariamente buscar pelo nome completo da mídia ele pode buscar por um sinônimo ou uma tag, por exemplo Game of Thrones pode ser buscado por GoT, mas mesmo que ele busque utilizando o termo GoT, quero que seja retornado Game of Thrones.

Comment: Mentira, expliquei tudo atoa, deu certo, fui eu quem comi barriga, tive que alterar umas coisinhas, ficou assim

`$sql = "(SELECT ayzac_midia_name,ayzac_midia_id,ayzac_midia_name FROM ayzac_midia WHERE ayzac_midia.ayzac_midia_name LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%') UNION (SELECT ayzac_tags.ayzac_tag,ayzac_tags.ayzac_midia_id, ayzac_midia.ayzac_midia_name FROM ayzac_tags INNER JOIN ayzac_midia ON ayzac_midia.ayzac_midia_id = ayzac_tags.ayzac_midia_id WHERE ayzac_tags.ayzac_tag LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%')";`

Answer (score 0):

Creio que você queira apenas 1 resultado de acordo com o termo procurado.

Segue:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT
  ayzac_midia_name,
  a.ayzac_midia_id 
FROM
  ayzac_midia a
JOIN
  ayzac_tags b on a.ayzac_midia_id = b.ayzac_midia_id
WHERE
  ayzac_midia_name LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%'
  OR ayzac_tag LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%'";
```

> [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f004a6/4)